# Access: Find lowest value of field from a specific date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named angle 2 columns

```
DATE | Angle

1/1/2017 | 16.123

1/1/2017 | 16.122

1/1/2017 | 16.121

1/2/2017 | 16.321

1/2/2017 | 16.524

1/2/2017 | 16.111
```

I would like a make table query that gives me the lowest angle for each date
to look like this:

```
1/1/2017 | 16.121

1/2/2017 | 16.111
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you need a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    DATE, MIN(Angle) AS min_angle
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DATE;
```